# How can I upload photos to a specific fansite album via email?

Tags: facebook

One can send photos to a fan site via a specific Facebook email address. e.g. `enix4dfsdapid@m.facebook.com`

These photos are uploaded to the news stream.

Is it possible to send these photos to a specific album?